# How to check if a domain contains an element in Chapel

Tags: sparse-matrix, chapel

Suppose I have a sparse domain and I want to check if an element has been added.

```
var D = {1..5, 1..5},
    SD: sparse subdomain(D);

SD += (1,3);
```

Now I want to see if `(1,3)` and `(2,3)` are in SD.  This is not correct and [this page](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/primers/associative.html?highlight=member) doesn't `.contain()` an example. HA!  See what I did there?

```
//Don't do this
SD.contains(1,3)  // want true;
SD.contains(2,3)  // want false;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Domains in Chapel all support a method with the signature [`member(i:idxType ...rank)`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/builtins/ChapelArray.html#ChapelArray.member) that returns `true` if the specified index is a member of the domain and `false` otherwise. This includes associative, opaque, rectangular, and sparse domains.  Examples for each of these types follow:

**Associative:**

```
var D: domain(string);
D += "hello";

writeln("Associative");
writeln(D.member("world")); // false
writeln(D.member("hello")); // true
```

**Opaque:**

```
var D: domain(opaque);
var i1 = D.create();
var i2: i1.type;

writeln("Opaque");
writeln(D.member(i2)); // false
writeln(D.member(i1)); // true
```

**Rectangular:**

```
  var D = {1..4, 3..5};

  writeln("Rectangular");
  writeln(D.member(2,6)); // false
  writeln(D.member(3,3)); // true
```

**Sparse:**

```
  var D = {1..10, 1..10};
  var SD: sparse subdomain(D);
  SD += (2,3);

  writeln("Sparse");
  writeln(SD.member(2,7)); // false
  writeln(SD.member(2,3)); // true
```